# GCS object on event-based hold

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have no issue with an object being on hold, but I think I might of used the feature wrong, or might not be understanding it.

```
Object '(BUCKET)/S04E02.mp3' is under active Event-Based hold and cannot be deleted, overwritten or archived until hold is removed.
```

So one of the things I want to achieve, is that if a user deletes an item (audio file) from our GCS, and then realises that they made a mistake I want them to be able to restore the object.

However I don't think there should be a hold on the object from the time the object is uploaded to our system, as people often upload a wrong file.

I am wondering what settings do I need in my GCS to make it possible to delete an uploaded file but also restore it in GCS.

[image: GCS settings]
[image: Lifecycle Settings]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the doc related to [Deleted Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects) and [Deleted Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-buckets#delete-bucket)  :

> Object deletion cannot be undone. Cloud Storage is designed to give
> developers a high amount of flexibility and control over their data,
> and Google maintains strict controls over the processing and purging
> of deleted data. To protect yourself from mistakes, see Options for
> controlling data lifecycles.
>
> Deleting a bucket also deletes any objects stored within the bucket.
> These objects cannot be recovered. For tools to prevent accidental
> data deletion.

You already mentioned in your Question regarding the [Data Lifecycle](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/control-data-lifecycles) and following information is provided in the Public documentation for controlling data lifecycle :

> If you are concerned that your application software or users might erroneously delete or replace objects at some point, Cloud Storage has
> features that help you protect your data:
>
> - A [retention policy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock) that specifies a retention period can be [placed on a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-bucket-lock#set-policy). An object in the bucket cannot be deleted or
>   replaced until it reaches the specified age.
> - An [object hold](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-holds) can be [placed on individual objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/holding-objects#set-object-hold) to prevent anyone from deleting or replacing the object until the hold is
>   removed.
> - [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) can be enabled on a bucket in order to retain older versions of objects. When the live version of an object is
>   deleted or replaced, it becomes noncurrent if versioning is enabled on
>   the bucket. If you accidentally delete a live object version, you can
>   [restore the noncurrent version](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-versioned-objects#restore) of it back to the live version.
>   Caution: Object Versioning does not protect your data if you [delete
>   the entire bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-buckets).    Object Versioning increases storage costs,
>   but this can be partially mitigated by configuring [Object Lifecycle
>   Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) to delete older object versions. For one possible
>   setup, see the lifecycle configuration example for [deleting
>   objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle-configurations#deletion-example).
> - [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) can be configured for a bucket, which gives you more automated control over deleting objects. When you
>   define a lifecycle configuration, Cloud Storage performs a specified
>   action on an object only if the object meets your criteria.

> Answer to your this Question :  if a user deletes an item (audio file)
> from our GCS, and then realizes that they made a mistake

If someone had accidentally deleted  an object or bucket then it's recommended  to [contact Google support and raise ticket](https://cloud.google.com/contact#:%7E:text=Get%20support%20for%20my%20current%20Google%20Cloud%20product%28s%29)  and provide the Project specific details as following :

1. When was the object versioning enabled (date & time)?
2. What [object lifecycle management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) was put in place for the noncurrent version and bucket?
3. Have you tried to use [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-versioned-objects#restore) to restore the objects?
4. Deletion date and time of objects.

Comment: @RussellHarrower Posted an answer , is it helpful?